# Conectar com SQL Server em servidor remoto

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Preciso me conectar com um serviço de SQL Server em um servidor remoto via SQLConnection, C#. Inicialmente, estava dando que não era possível encontrar o servidor, mas resolvi isto modificando o arquivo hosts da system32, habilitando exceção no firewall do servidor e habilitando o SQL Server Browser. Porém, agora ele me dá uma exceção dizendo "O tempo limite de espera foi atingido" ao tentar abrir conexão com o banco. O que devo fazer?

Segue exemplo da connection string que estou usando: 
"Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/MSSQLSERVER, 1433;Database=meuBanco;User Id=sa;Password = ************;"

Comment: No meu web.Conf eu uso assim:    `<add name="cepConnectionString" connectionString="Password=senha;Persist Security Info=True;Connect Timeout=450;User ID=usuario;Initial Catalog=banco;Data Source=servidor" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`.
Uma pergunta você habilitou seu banco para client?

Comment: Você diz habilitar conexão remota no servidor do SQL?

Comment: Isso no banco instalado no servidor.

Comment: Sim, habilitei no SQL Server, puis exceção no firewall e habilitei o sql server browser. Mas ele tava dando que excedo o tempo limite

Comment: Você deu permissão pro IIS acessar o banco?

Comment: Como assim? Estou querendo acessar o SQL a partir de uma aplicação Windows Forms, o IIS interfere?

Comment: Não Não, achei que era Web. Cara tá dificil saber o que pode ser. Já entrou pelo mangament studio pra saber se tá rolando? Já tentou usar a minha ConnectionString que postei?

Comment: Então, pelo management studio eu abri as propriedades do servidor e habilitei conexão remota. No SQL Server Configuration manager habilitei o sql server browser e configurei o TCP/IP. Quando coloco a minha string ele acusa que esgotou o tempo limite de espera e a sua ele fala que o host nao foi reconhecido rsrs

Comment: Tá faltando alguma coisinha. Mais você está no caminho certo.

Comment: Alguma ideia mais do que eu possa tentar?

Comment: Você habilitou os serviços?

Comment: Sim. SQL Server, Sql Server Browsere os de redes estão todos habilitados

Comment: Você consegue acessar o banco utilizando o [Management Studio (SSMS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/mt238290.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Uma coisa que acontece em alguns servidores que já mexi é que você não precisa especificar a instância em caso de conexão remota.

Experimente usar apenas:

```
Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433;Database=meuBanco;User Id=sa;Password=************;
```